# JQuery .load() loads more pages after every click

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

Since JQuery is the solution to everything in life I use it to load pages with the `.load()` function after clicking a link with a certain class, see below code: 
`$('.pageloader').click(function(){
    $('.content').load("pages/" + this.name);
});`

This, however, loads twice the amount of pages after every click (1 the first time, 2 after, 4, 8, 16 etc).

I have tried turning off all other code but it does not change anything.
Using console.log I've noticed that it only performs the `.click()` function once, and it is the `.load()` that's being executed multiple times.

Would anyone know what could be causing this?

Comment: Do you by any chance have two elements having class "content"?

Comment: @Aioros No I don't. If I did it should still only load twice for every click, not twice as much for every click.

Comment: As @Aioros said, is it possible that the page you're loading contains the code executed? If so you're inserting `$('.pageloader').click(function(){ $('.content').load("pages/" + this.name); });` at every click.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably binding few times the click event...

Add this before `.click` :

```
$('.pageloader').unbind('click').off('click');
$('.pageloader').click(function(){ $('.content').empty().load("pages/" + this.name); });
```

[EDIT]

The problem was in the loaded page.

Comment: TypeError: $(...).unbind(...).die is not a function. It's not calling the .click function multiple times, I used console.log to very it and only got 1 console line but multiple loads.

Comment: Now it doesn't give me the error, but it doesn't change the amount of loads.

Comment: Do you have any JS in the loaded page? Maybe the problem is in!

Comment: I found the problem just now before reading your latest comment, but it is correct. On the next page i call exactly the same JQuery code.....awkward. Changed the class selector and it works perfectly now. Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this once:

```
$('.pageloader').click(function () {
    // Cache this here
    var $this = $(this);

    // Removes all child nodes (including text nodes) from content class
    $('.content').empty().load("pages/" + $this.attr('name'));
});
```

Comment: Tried it, does not change the amount of loads. To clarify, the problem is NOT that it's loading multiple pages into one div, my problem is that it's loading multiple pages.

Comment: I think if it's just a content problem, Parrotmaster shouldn't see few loadings in consol.log...